Can you port a web app to mobile with Capacitor, without using WebView and server for serving the HTML files?
I am fairly new to Capacitor and mobile apps in general. I am using the Quasar framework for building my front-end web apps.
Until now I was under the impression that Capacitor, would somehow port the HTML/CSS/JS code into native Android and iOS components, that would work without the need for a web server.
Recently I built the the first .apk with Android Web Studio and Capacitor, and during the process I realized that all that Capacitor does, is wrapping my web page in a Web View, basically giving me a browser-like rendering engine wrapped in a mobile app. The mobile app would not work offline, without access to the server.
I tried googling on the subject but most of the answers are how to change the URL from localhost to some remote server, which is not what I want.
Is it possible to build a mobile app, that is not dependent on a server to run?
Maybe the solution can be just to pack the HTML/CSS/JS locally on the mobile app, instead of requesting them via HTTP from a remote server?
I am building the app with quasar with the following command:
quasar dev -m capacitor -T android

The command opens Android Studio, and the build is done from there.
When I install the .apk file on my phone, I get an ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE, because the phone is trying to reach my development server via a private address.

And then? What would your frontend (app) do? If you code a frontend that depends on a backend/server and pack said frontend into a apk, what do you expect to happen? How should this magical work without server?

@Marc, maybe a simple javascript calculator... Maybe a game.
I am exploring, just want to know how this technology works, and what are the limitations.

Your rigt.If you code a calculator that does the computing all in the frontend then you need no server and you can simply pack that into a apk. May explain with more details what the issue is? Im currently no sure what problem you are facing.

@Marc, I had a problem that I was building a development version that was rellying on my dev server.
I was able to build a version that is server independend, buy building a production version with different build parameters.
I am pretty new to this, so I did not know where to look and what to ask for

The problem was that I was building a dev apk that was relient on the quasar dev server:
quasar dev -m capacitor -T android

Where I should have been doing:
quasar build -m capacitor -T android

After building for production, you need to zipalign and sign the apk, as specified in the quasar docs:
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-capacitor-apps/publishing-to-store


The mobile app would not work offline, without access to the server.

No, the mobile app will work offline without needing access to an external server. It creates a local server on the phone itself, and the distribution files are packed within the APK. The WebView created with Capacitor loads these files directly from the APK, not from a remote server.
I hope this helps.
